# How to find the references that are included in the reference list but not cited?

Tags: cross-referencing

My co-author refuses to use .bib files, preferring to have a bibliography list within one main .tex document. For example:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{K50}
H. Kuhn, Extensive games,
Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. 36 (1950) 286--295.

\bibitem{S53}
L. Shapley, Stochastic games, 
Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA 39 (1953) 1095--1100.
```

When the reference list is too long, it's a pain to check whether each source was actually cited and they will all appear in the list. I know how to do it with .bib but not sure if it's possible within one .tex document. We work in Overleaf.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcheck

Answer (score 1):

you could use backref. It will insert a link to the entries which are cited (be careful, to have empty lines between the entries):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{some text}
\cite{K50}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{K50}
H. Kuhn, Extensive games,
Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. 36 (1950) 286--295.

\bibitem{S53}
L. Shapley, Stochastic games, 
Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA 39 (1953) 1095--1100. 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]